# Forward declaration in package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question and I am not finding the answer from google.
This may be a simple question since I'm a beginner I have this doubt.

Can we declare a function in Package specification and use the same function for forward declaration ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pckg_test IS
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
PROCEDURE proc_test (id number);
END pckg_test ;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pckg_test IS 
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER; --fwd declaration
PROCEDURE proc_test (id number) is 
BEGIN
....
calling fun_test
....
END;
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER is
BEGIN
....
END;
END pckg_test;
```

Comment: I think you don't need forward declaration if you already have specification.

Comment: so it means i can give fwd declaration only for private subprograms ?

Comment: @Sas - do you really mean "I **can** give fwd declaration only for private subprograms", or did you mean "I **need to** give fwd declaration only for private subprograms"? Why would you **want** to give declaration in the package body, when the PL/SQL architecture is that functions are declared (forward!) in the package specification?

Comment: @mathguy I was not aware of that functions are forward declared in spec. and I meant " I need to give".
But now I understood the concept. thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (forward) declare the function in the body, because it has already been declared in the specification.

This is simple to test with very minor filling-out of your pseudocode:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pckg_test IS
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
PROCEDURE proc_test (id number);
END pckg_test ;
/

Package PCKG_TEST compiled

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pckg_test IS 
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER; --fwd declaration
PROCEDURE proc_test (id number) is 
  x number;
BEGIN
  x := fun_test(1);
END;
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER is
BEGIN
  return 42;
END;
END pckg_test;
/

Package Body PCKG_TEST compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/1       PLS-00305: previous use of 'FUN_TEST' (at line 2) conflicts with this use
2/1       PL/SQL: Item ignored
2/10      PLS-00328: A subprogram body must be defined for the forward declaration of FUN_TEST.
Errors: check compiler log
```

The PLS-00305 is because of your forward declaration, which is the same (name and data types) as that in the package specification.

The PLS-00328 is slightly misleading; the full declaration of `fun_test` seems to be being linked to the public specification, and the forward declaration - even though it is itself throwing an error - then has no matching full declaration.

If you just remove or comment out the forward declaration then it compiles successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pckg_test IS 
--FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER; --fwd declaration
PROCEDURE proc_test (id number) is 
  x number;
BEGIN
  x := fun_test(1);
END;
FUNCTION fun_test(ID NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER is
BEGIN
  return 42;
END;
END pckg_test;
/

Package Body PCKG_TEST compiled
```

You don't need (and are not alowed) a forward declaration of `fun_test` within the package body because it is publicly declared in the package specification - that public spec makes the function available throughout the package body. So, `proc_test` can still call `fun_test` even though it comes first in the body code. The public specification has the same effect as a forward declaration would.

> so it means i can give fwd declaration only for private subprograms ?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation.